# Android: findViewById returns Null even if is after setContentView

Tags: android, null, oncreate, findviewbyid

Here's my code in LoginActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onLoginButtonClicked();
        }
    });

    // Check if there is a currently logged in user
    // and they are linked to a Facebook account.
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if ((currentUser != null) && ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(currentUser)) {
        // Go to the main activity
        showHomeActivity();
    }
}
```

in fragment_login.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/login_button" />
```

And this is the log when i run the application:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(6647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(6647): Process: com.moostachestudio.drinkitapp, PID: 6647
E/AndroidRuntime(6647): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.moostachestudio.drinkitapp/com.moostachestudio.drinkitapp.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at com.moostachestudio.drinkitapp.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(6647):     ... 11 more
```

The problem is that "loginButton" is NULL but i don't know why, because i call the findViewById after the setContentView!

Comment: I think (not sure) you have to use `findViewById` in the `Fragment` if the button is in the `Fragment`.

Comment: What he says...put it in the fragments onCreate.

Comment: I tryed to change the setContentView with setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login); but it doesn't work

Comment: I create the activity and eclipse generate 2 xml activity_login and fragment_login but just one .java file, so i have only one onCreate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `Button` is in fragment layout, so **your on click method might be in your fragment** (`PlaceholderFragment`) instead of your activity. You need to declare another Class extends with Fragment..

First, create a new Class named `PlaceHolderFragment`. Extend it with `Fragment` and add this code below to it:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    // ...
    loginButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onLoginButtonClicked();
        }
    });
    // ...
    return rootView;
}  

// put your method onLoginButtonClicked here.
```

Then, your layout activity for `MainActivity` (named `activity_main`) might have a `FrameLayout` with the id container like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!-- other views -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Finally, your `MainActivity` will only have:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // you add you fragment here in id container
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    // ... without loginButton
    // and some more stuff
}
```

Comment: I tryed this solution and it seems to work, the problem is that now inside the onCreateView i can't reach my onLoginButtonClicked() function

Comment: put your `loginButtonClicked` method inside your Fragment. And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the button inside onCreate, rather than declaring it outside of it (which is what I'm assuming you're doing).

Oh, and if you haven't tried this already, use "VIEW.findViewById(R.id.loginButton)", rather than just "findViewById(R.id.loginButton);". I think that's more likely your problem; I forget about it a lot too.